# signal-slot in Qt : emit is located in the slot method

Tags: qt, signals-slots

i'm reading a book about Qt, in one of the examples of a signal-slot function, there is the emit method located inside the slot method... So this becomes an infinite loop... i don't really understand how to stop it :

```
connect(webView, SIGNAL(urlChanged(const QUrl&)), 
    this, SLOT(urlChange(const QUrl&));
```

and we then have the function :

```
void BrowserWindow::urlChange(const QUrl &url)
{
    emit urlChanged(url);
    progressLabel->setText(tr("Loading"));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is webView? (is it the same type?)

The connect is connecting one instance with this slot - its probably not connecting its own instance.

If it was

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(urlChanged(const QUrl&)), 
        this, SLOT(urlChange(const QUrl&));
```

then that would be an infinite loop

Comment: oops, yes you're right, but there is still emit called at least one time when the slot is called, and i'm not sure why, the text says : "we emit our own urlChanged() signal as a convenience to BrowserWindow users" but i don't understand what this really means, since the only "urlChanged" signal is set to the webview instance (webView is of type QWebView)...

Comment: This emit would be for any slots that might be connected to BrowserWindow. Something may change the BrowserWindow url (say, clicking a button), and then BrowserWindow will emit because it got changed, and its emit can trigger another slot in the pipeline (ie, activate a different button). Without the BrowserWindow emit, we can't chain these together - but with it, we can.

Comment: Thanks Will, okay, the thing is there is no "connect" method that is listening to this emit from "this" (BrowserWindow), but okay i understand the principle, Thanks for your help! Cheers